# what on earth is an FRO? (in relation to databases)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building a mysql database for a company and was just asked if it can output an 'FRO'

the only information I can find is a tiny entry here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fro in broken english that says "a file format which is used by the SQL database on the Network Element"

Comment: http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/FRO-Compiled-report-dBase-IV

Comment: Good God that's ancient. why anybody would ask for that is beyond me...